# gdal_translate producing tif with different colors as original

Tags: gdal, enterprise-geodatabase, color, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt

I am using ArcSDE as my raster data source with the ultimate goal  to tile this dataset: I am running the following  gdal_translate command to generate the initial VRT:

```
gdal_translate  -projwin 390605 5588320 410128 5568805 -a_srs EPSG:25832 -a_nodata none -of vrt SDE:server,5153,db,user,pw,table,image clippedvrt.vrt
```

Tiling the resultant VRT produces tiff with weird colors. The colors are either intensified or totally different from the original as you can see from the [test results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-iJv3cImO7bkZYRVZERi1rTTg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the result of gdalinfo on the resultant VRT:

```
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
0: -1,-1,-1,255
1: 0,0,-1,255
2: -1,22873,22873,255
3: 26214,13107,0,255
4: -1,22873,22873,255
5: 26214,-17734,-1,255
6: -1,-3342,22873,255
7: 0,-6683,0,255
8: 0,0,0,255
9: -19790,26214,0,255
10: -13108,-1,-13108,255
11: 0,0,0,255
12: -11052,-11052,-11052,255
13: -13108,-1,-1,255
14: -3342,-10538,-21846,255
15: 26214,13107,0,255
16: -19276,-32640,26214,255
17: -1,-1,-1,255
18: -1,-1,-1,255
19: -1,-1,-1,255
20: -1,-1,-1,255
21: -1,-1,-1,255
22: -1,-1,-1,255
23: -1,-1,-1,255
24: -1,-1,-1,255
```

Could someone shed some light as to what might be happening?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and had to do an extra run with

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\%%~nN.vrt
```

to expand the palettes used in the tifs to RGBA. Every tif has a different palette stored, and that's why stitching them together gives weired colours.

In the next step, I did

```
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index.vrt NL50\*.vrt
```

Comment: The input is from an SDE raster dataset, so I would be surprised if the issue was the difference in palettes stored. A preliminary test adding the -expand rgba option to the dataset leads to even weirder colors. BTW, the SDEraster I am using is an 8-bit image

Comment: The palette of the vrt generated without the -expand option is:  ´Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: -1,-1,-1,255
    1: 0,0,-1,255
    2: -1,22873,22873,255
    3: 26214,13107,0,255
    4: -1,22873,22873,255
    5: 26214,-17734,-1,255
    6: -1,-3342,22873,255
    7: 0,-6683,0,255
    8: 0,0,0,255
    9: -19790,26214,0,255
   10: -13108,-1,-13108,255
   11: 0,0,0,255
   12: -11052,-11052,-11052,255
   13: -13108,-1,-1,255
   14: -3342,-10538,-21846,255
   15: 26214,13107,0,255
   16: -19276,-32640,26214,255
   17: -1,-1,-1,255`

Comment: Strange. That Color Palette does not make sense to me. All values should be between 0 and 255. Can you add the color table definition of the .vrt file into your question? You can look into the file with any text editor.

Comment: After some further test, I did not go any further. I did a gdalinfo directly on the SDE source and it resulted in that weird palette I already posted. As I said before i tried applying -scale and -expand options but, nothing changed. It seemed to me that the problem was with gdal-translate, so I tried generating the VRT via gdalbuildvrt cmd and alas, same output - vrt with exactly the same palette. Strange thing is, when we create a small tiff out of the raster using ArcGIS we get a correctly paletted tif

Comment: You can edit the color palette manually in the vrt file if you have the right values from the small tif. I assume this to be a bug of the driver.